# SQLite not displaying new columns via UI after ADD COLUMN

Tags: c#, sqlite

I added a new column to an existing table, and when I open this database via "SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable_3.12.2", I don't see a new field, as if it doesn't exist, although I can see it through the code. What am I doing wrong? How to make the field appear on the UI.
(see the image below).

```
using (SQLiteConnection database = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
{
    database.Open();

    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(database);
    //add new COLUMN just for test
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE entities ADD COLUMN PublishDate DateTime;";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   //some logic..
 }
```

I also tried like this:

```
var trans = database.BeginTransaction();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("ALTER TABLE entities ADD COLUMN NewNewPublish DateTime;", database, trans);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
trans.Commit();
```

[image]

Comment: DateTime isn't a valid datatype in SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  You'll need to either convert to string or store the epoch as integer.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Good day, thanks for try to help me, I am a beginner and have not worked with databases, that is probably what you are asking about:
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\entities.sqlite;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings> 
 private static string LoadConnectionString(string id = "Default")
{
  return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
}
I used Dapper (Nuget package).
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(database, database); - there is no such constructor.

Comment: @bschellekens Hi, I can manually create such a type in the database without any problem, this string was given as an example, if I change it to a valid type nothing will change.

Comment: database.CreateCommand() - result is the same, in code I see new property for current column, but if I open this DB via app, I do not see change. I have a simple task to create a new property through code.

Comment: @DimaSchepetkov I made a typo (I wanted to write `new SQLiteCommand(sql, database)` thus your call to the constructor is fine). I only know [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) and now I use [SQLiteNet ORM](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) based on [SQLitePCL.raw](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw). SQLite has few [types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): you can store date and time as text (slow), real (never used) or integer (conventional). I see that SQLiteNet is storing DateTime.Ticks as BIGINT in my tables structure (an "alias" for INTEGER).

Comment: @OlivierRogier As I wrote above, I can put a different type of data (string, int, etc...) into it, but it won't have any effect on the result. sql - it's just a string, but what should it contain? How do I solve the problem? Writing to the database happens, successfully, but I can only see it through VS.

Comment: What happens if you execute the query in a sql browser like sqlitestudio?

Comment: If I open my DB via "SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable_3.12.2" and execute the same command, I see a new field is added to the current row.

Comment: What happens if you use another provider instead of Dapper? SQLite.org, or SQLiteNet that is very fine for direct SQL as well as a little Code First ORM.

Comment: I'm a beginner, I don't even know how to do it. :(

Comment: Just search in VS nuget manager wizard "sqlite v3.13.0" (I never used it) or "sqlite-net-pcl v1.7.335" and install it, then just change your code and usings, and run.

Comment: Got it, I will try, thanks for support!